# How to find the SMA starting from a given repetition factor?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, orbital-elements, orbit-determination

I need a help for an orbit design problem.
My constraint is that the height is 480 km, the repetition factor has to be Q = 245/16 and the orbit must be sun-synchronous. I would like to find the SMA starting from this Q value.
At a first step of approximation, I had set SMA = height+6378 km, but now I have to refine (considering also the fact that real orbits are not perfectly circular). Can anyone help me?

Comment: How important is it that the orbit be sun-synchronous, and reach that particular altitude? From the Keplerian-Newtonian two-body  simplification, all you need is the orbital period (calculatable from your Repetition factor and the length of a sidereal day) and the gravitational parameter of Earth to calculate the semi-major axis.